# Directive not working in Angularjs, Not getting called

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write formatter and parser through a directive.

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('toDate', function(){
        debugger; //Debugger Not Coming Here
        return{
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
                debugger; //Debugger Not Coming Here Too
                ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value){
                        return new Date(value);
                });

                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value){
                    if(typeof value === 'object'){
                        return value.getTime();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

using it in view :

```
 <td><input type="text"  ng-model="item.s_modified_on" toDate /></td>
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 <td><input type="text"  ng-model="item.s_modified_on" to-date /></td>
```

instead of

```
 <td><input type="text"  ng-model="item.s_modified_on" toDate /></td>
```

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive